# How do I disable the taskbar/menubar in LXDE on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I am trying to get rid of the taskbar/menubar completely but I can not find how to do it either by googling or going through the menus offered by LXDE. Under 'Appearance Settings' I am only able to set the size and position of the menubar but there is no option to remove it.

Is there a file I can edit in order to remove the menubar and if so, what should I look for in this file in order to accomplish this?

By taskbar/menubar I mean the bar that is visible on the top/bottom of the desktop which contains some program shortcuts and displays the time among other things.

Comment: Run only `openbox` windowmanager, and don't run `lxpanel`.

Comment: @IporSircer Slightly off-topic here...this is a bug report https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467199/mousepad-not-working-in-lenovo-thinkpad/467200

Answer (score 6):

To disable the taskbar you need to edit the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and comment the line (with #):

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
```

On the next boot, the menu should have disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Almost...

You also need to comment out that line in the home directory configuration file `~pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. Otherwise, it will take over.
ie:

```
vi /home/pi/config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
#@lxpanel --profile LXDE
```

Then reboot.

Comment: how do i exit vi? I'm stuck!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Raspbian Buster, edit `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file and comment `@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi` line. It is usually the first line.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however that this is exactly what the OP proposed in the accepted answer (save for the profile name). If your answer was meant to add a different aspect, please edit it to make that clearer.